# Are there memset function implementations that fill the buffer in reverse order?

Tags: c++, c, memset

I know that there are implementations of `memcpy`, which copied memory in reverse order to optimize for some processors. At one time, a bug "[Strange sound on mp3 flash website](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638477)" was connected with that. Well, it was an interesting story, but my question is about another function.

I am wondering, there is a `memset` function in the world, which fills the buffer, starting from the end. It is clear that in theory nothing prevents doing such an implementation of a function. But I am interested exactly in the fact that this function was done in practice by someone somewhere. I would be especially grateful on the link on the library with such a function.

P.S. I understand that in terms of applications programming it has completely no difference whether the buffer is filled in the ascending or descending order. However, it is important for me to find out whether there was any "reverse" function implementation. I need it for writing an article.

Comment: Possibly there are such implementation, the standard doesn't specify anything about the order. If some software depends on the fact that memcpy copies top down instead of bottom up then that software is broken.

Comment: Performance properties may depend on it, e.g. in terms of what's fresh in the cache after memset.

Comment: @R.. - Whether there's some such implementation somewhere in the world on some platform presumably isn't going to help one with one's performance problems ;)

Comment: One could argu that test for zero is faster than test for a specific value `while (i < n)` take more time than `while (n > 0)`. So implementation start from the end to the begin for win time on the test of while and use only one variable to decrement to zero.

Comment: @Stargateur: OP is writing an article that presumably already warns about the need to use `memmove`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160544/discussion-between-stargateur-and-r).

Comment: The article: Why it is important to check what the malloc function returned - https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0558/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Linux kernel's memset for the SuperH architecture has this property:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/sh/lib/memset.S?id=v4.14

Presumably it's done this way because the mov instruction exists in predecrement form (`mov.l Rm,@-Rn`) but not postincrement form. See:

http://shared-ptr.com/sh_insns.html

If you want something that's not technically kernel internals on a freestanding implementation, but an actual hosted C implementation that application code could get linked to, musl libc also has an example:

https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/memset.c?id=v1.1.18

Here, the C version of memset (used on many but not all target archs) does not actually fill the whole buffer backwards, but rather starts from both the beginning and end in a manner that reduces the number of conditional branches and makes them all predictable for very small memsets. See the commit message where it was added for details:

https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/string/memset.c?id=a543369e3b06a51eacd392c738fc10c5267a195f

Some of the arch-specific asm versions of memset also have this property:

https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/x86_64/memset.s?id=v1.1.18